# MYSQL Error: Incorrect usage of UNION and ORDER BY?

Tags: mysql, sql-server-2008, query, subquery

Am trying to randomize my first query but ran into an error "Incorrect usage of UNION and ORDER BY" Kindly find below my queries:

```
SELECT *
FROM(
        SELECT deal_page.id,
            deal_page.merchant_id,
            deal_page.category_id,
            deal_page.emirate_id,
            deal_page.title,
            deal_page.description,
            deal_page.emirate,
            deal_page.lat,
            deal_page.lng,
            deal_page.address,
            deal_page.thumbnail_name,
            deal_page.price,
            deal_page.created_at,
            AVG(ratings.ratings) AS rating
        FROM deal_page
            LEFT JOIN ratings ON deal_page.id = ratings.deal_id
        GROUP BY deal_page.id,
            deal_page.merchant_id,
            deal_page.category_id,
            deal_page.emirate_id,
            deal_page.title,
            deal_page.description,
            deal_page.emirate,
            deal_page.lat,
            deal_page.lng,
            deal_page.address,
            deal_page.thumbnail_name,
            deal_page.price,
            deal_page.created_at
        ORDER BY deal_page.lat ASC
        LIMIT 2
    ) t1 ORDER BY RAND()
UNION DISTINCT
SELECT *
FROM(
        SELECT deal_page.id,
            deal_page.merchant_id,
            deal_page.category_id,
            deal_page.emirate_id,
            deal_page.title,
            deal_page.description,
            deal_page.emirate,
            deal_page.lat,
            deal_page.lng,
            deal_page.address,
            deal_page.thumbnail_name,
            deal_page.price,
            deal_page.created_at,
            AVG(ratings.ratings) AS rating
        FROM deal_page
            LEFT JOIN ratings ON deal_page.id = ratings.deal_id
        GROUP BY deal_page.id,
            deal_page.merchant_id,
            deal_page.category_id,
            deal_page.emirate_id,
            deal_page.title,
            deal_page.description,
            deal_page.emirate,
            deal_page.lat,
            deal_page.lng,
            deal_page.address,
            deal_page.thumbnail_name,
            deal_page.price,
            deal_page.created_at
        ORDER BY deal_page.lat ASC
    ) t2
```

Am not sure where I got it wrong. Without adding "ORDER BY RAND()" my query runs well but I need the first query to randomize. I need a guide on how to come about this.

Comment: Put `ORDER BY RAND()` after the last subquery (after `) t2`). And remove ORDER BY clause from subquery `t2` - it makes no sense without LIMIT clause.

Comment: Adding ORDER BY RAND() after the last subquery will randomize the final query. I want the first query to be randomized before the second query. Any help with that?

Comment: Are you using SQL Server or MySQL?

Comment: Please don't cross post to multiple sites. https://stackoverflow.com/q/63199382/3404097

Comment: You say you "not sure where I got it wrong" but the only description you give of what you want is the vague "randomize my first query " & code that doesn't do it. Explain what you want. For code questions give a [mre]. Please research before considering posting a question, including error messages, including reading the manual.

Comment: What do you _want_?  2 random rows from the first query plus 1 row from the second, but only if different?  So you end up with 2 or 3 rows, in no particular order?  Please point out what, if anything, is different in the second `SELECT`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simoly put around the Select ... ORDER BY RAND() in parenthesis, so that MysSQL knows how to process it

```
(SELECT *
FROM
( 
    SELECT hobber_deal_page.id,
        hobber_deal_page.merchant_id,
        hobber_deal_page.category_id,
        hobber_deal_page.emirate_id,
        hobber_deal_page.title,
        hobber_deal_page.description,
        hobber_deal_page.emirate,
        hobber_deal_page.lat,
        hobber_deal_page.lng,
        hobber_deal_page.address,
        hobber_deal_page.thumbnail_name,
        hobber_deal_page.price,
        hobber_deal_page.created_at,
        AVG(hobber_ratings.ratings) AS ratings
    FROM hobber_deal_page
        LEFT JOIN hobber_ratings ON hobber_deal_page.id = hobber_ratings.deal_id
    GROUP BY hobber_deal_page.id,
        hobber_deal_page.merchant_id,
        hobber_deal_page.category_id,
        hobber_deal_page.emirate_id,
        hobber_deal_page.title,
        hobber_deal_page.description,
        hobber_deal_page.emirate,
        hobber_deal_page.lat,
        hobber_deal_page.lng,
        hobber_deal_page.address,
        hobber_deal_page.thumbnail_name,
        hobber_deal_page.price,
        hobber_deal_page.created_at
    ORDER BY hobber_deal_page.lat ASC
    
    LIMIT 2
) t1 ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 18446744073709551615)
UNION DISTINCT
(SELECT *
FROM(
    SELECT hobber_deal_page.id,
        hobber_deal_page.merchant_id,
        hobber_deal_page.category_id,
        hobber_deal_page.emirate_id,
        hobber_deal_page.title,
        hobber_deal_page.description,
        hobber_deal_page.emirate,
        hobber_deal_page.lat,
        hobber_deal_page.lng,
        hobber_deal_page.address,
        hobber_deal_page.thumbnail_name,
        hobber_deal_page.price,
        hobber_deal_page.created_at,
        AVG(hobber_ratings.ratings) AS ratings
    FROM hobber_deal_page
        LEFT JOIN hobber_ratings ON hobber_deal_page.id = hobber_ratings.deal_id
    GROUP BY hobber_deal_page.id,
        hobber_deal_page.merchant_id,
       hobber_deal_page.category_id,
        hobber_deal_page.emirate_id,
      hobber_deal_page.title,
        hobber_deal_page.description,
        hobber_deal_page.emirate,
        hobber_deal_page.lat,
        hobber_deal_page.lng,
        hobber_deal_page.address,
        hobber_deal_page.thumbnail_name,
        hobber_deal_page.price,
        hobber_deal_page.created_at
    ORDER BY hobber_deal_page.lat ASC
) t2)
```

Basically something like this, but as i mentioned ion the comment without testd data, it is not clear, if this is he solution

```
(SELECT *
FROM
( 
    SELECT hobber_deal_page.id,
        hobber_deal_page.merchant_id,
        hobber_deal_page.category_id,
        hobber_deal_page.emirate_id,
        hobber_deal_page.title,
        hobber_deal_page.description,
        hobber_deal_page.emirate,
        hobber_deal_page.lat,
        hobber_deal_page.lng,
        hobber_deal_page.address,
        hobber_deal_page.thumbnail_name,
        hobber_deal_page.price,
        hobber_deal_page.created_at,
        AVG(hobber_ratings.ratings) AS ratings
    FROM hobber_deal_page
        LEFT JOIN hobber_ratings ON hobber_deal_page.id = hobber_ratings.deal_id
    GROUP BY hobber_deal_page.id,
        hobber_deal_page.merchant_id,
        hobber_deal_page.category_id,
        hobber_deal_page.emirate_id,
        hobber_deal_page.title,
        hobber_deal_page.description,
        hobber_deal_page.emirate,
        hobber_deal_page.lat,
        hobber_deal_page.lng,
        hobber_deal_page.address,
        hobber_deal_page.thumbnail_name,
        hobber_deal_page.price,
        hobber_deal_page.created_at
    ORDER BY hobber_deal_page.lat ASC        
    LIMIT 2
) t1 ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 18446744073709551615)
UNION DISTINCT
(SELECT *
FROM(
    SELECT hobber_deal_page.id,
        hobber_deal_page.merchant_id,
        hobber_deal_page.category_id,
        hobber_deal_page.emirate_id,
        hobber_deal_page.title,
        hobber_deal_page.description,
        hobber_deal_page.emirate,
        hobber_deal_page.lat,
        hobber_deal_page.lng,
        hobber_deal_page.address,
        hobber_deal_page.thumbnail_name,
        hobber_deal_page.price,
        hobber_deal_page.created_at,
        AVG(hobber_ratings.ratings) AS ratings
    FROM hobber_deal_page
        LEFT JOIN hobber_ratings ON hobber_deal_page.id = hobber_ratings.deal_id
        WHERE  hobber_deal_page.id NOT IN (SELECT hobber_deal_page.id
    FROM hobber_deal_page
        LEFT JOIN hobber_ratings ON hobber_deal_page.id = hobber_ratings.deal_id
    GROUP BY hobber_deal_page.id,
        hobber_deal_page.merchant_id,
        hobber_deal_page.category_id,
        hobber_deal_page.emirate_id,
        hobber_deal_page.title,
        hobber_deal_page.description,
        hobber_deal_page.emirate,
        hobber_deal_page.lat,
        hobber_deal_page.lng,
        hobber_deal_page.address,
        hobber_deal_page.thumbnail_name,
        hobber_deal_page.price,
        hobber_deal_page.created_at
    ORDER BY hobber_deal_page.lat ASC        
    LIMIT 2)
    GROUP BY hobber_deal_page.id,
        hobber_deal_page.merchant_id,
       hobber_deal_page.category_id,
        hobber_deal_page.emirate_id,
      hobber_deal_page.title,
        hobber_deal_page.description,
        hobber_deal_page.emirate,
        hobber_deal_page.lat,
        hobber_deal_page.lng,
        hobber_deal_page.address,
        hobber_deal_page.thumbnail_name,
        hobber_deal_page.price,
        hobber_deal_page.created_at
    ORDER BY hobber_deal_page.lat ASC
) t2)
```

Comment: I try to run the above query and it still didn't randomize. I want the LIMIT 2 to randomize whenever the query is initialized.

Comment: the first select 2 rows with the specified order, than the 2 get a random but with two rows only you must have luck to find another order: run this repeated and see of the order changes

Comment: I increased the limit to 5, and I ran it repeatedly but still no change. It is not randomizing. What should I do to improve the query?

Comment: databass are by nature unsorted, so the optumizer eliminates the ORDER By. Try the updated query, that forces the order

Comment: Amazing this work perfectly and I really appreciate it. Quick question what does the LIMIT 18446744073709551615 do? Can you explain it for me in details

Comment: it forces the optimizer not to remove the order by as i said. Please don't forget to [accept the answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: Of course, I will accept your answer. But I observed a row appears more than once in a row. For instance, a row appearing when I run the query 3 to 4 times at the same time. Have increased my limit to 5 and still same issue

Comment: you asked for help, solving your 1065 problem and i also helped woth the randomness. the perks with union and querys is another matter. stull you need a new question and this tmie add some data that shows your problem.

Comment: Order by has no meaning without top/limit when not at outermost level. Tables have no order, result sets do, so non-outermost order is lost after top/limit is applied. Order by is used with union by adding it after the last select. Read the manual re order by. @michaelisijola Ask a new question in a new post. But this answer is wrong.

Comment: The `ORDER BY` , even with the big limit will not survive the `UNION`.

Comment: To exclude, the id that you have already choosen, you nned to do the select in the second query also, but only get the hobber_deal_page.id and use NOT IN for that SELECT

Comment: @nbk Can you edit the code to perfect it to work as explained?

Comment: @michaelisijola Do not change questions after a reasonable answer has been posted, post a new question. [ask] [answer] [help] [meta] [meta.se]

Comment: you can try the updated answer, but as i said test data helps